# Javascript + jquery, function inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically i've got a lot of repetition in my code as im changing a few bits and pieces inside my function to accomodate the different divs such as class name, text and padding. Rather then writing them all out individually like so;

```
$('.about').hover(function () {
        $('.clickable7').text("Find out about us").css('padding-top', '137px').fadeIn(200);
        $('.positional').css("background-image", "none");
    },
    function () {
        $('.clickable7').fadeOut(200);
        $('.positional').css('background-image', 'url(assets/imgs/prototype6.png)');
    });
$('.friends').hover(function () {
        $('.clickable7').text("Meet our Friends").css('padding-top', '137px').fadeIn(200);
        $('.positional').css("background-image", "none");
    },
    function () {
        $('.clickable7').fadeOut(200);
        $('.positional').css('background-image', 'url(assets/imgs/prototype6.png)');
    });
```

I'm trying to write a function that will do it for me, i've gotten the functionality down but it kills the rest of my javascript code for some reason.

```
var titles = [
    {
        name: ".about",
        text: "find out about us",
        padding: 137
    },
    {
        name: ".friends",
        text: "meet our friends",
        padding: 137
    }
];

for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        var name = titles[index].name;
        var text = titles[index].text;
        var padding = titles[index].padding;

        $(name).hover(function () {
            $('.clickable7').text(text).css('padding-top', padding).fadeIn(200);
            $('.positional').css("background-image", "none");
        },
        function () {
            $('.clickable7').fadeOut(200);
            $('.positional').css('background-image', 'url(assets/imgs/prototype6.png)');
        });
    })(i);
};
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

edit--- my html

```
<div class="positional">
<a href="#about">
    <div class="about click">About</div>
</a>
<a href="#friends">
    <div class="friends click">Friends</div>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <div class="purpose click">Purpose</div>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <div class="empowerment click">Empowerment</div>
</a>
<a href="#contact">
    <div class="contact click">Contact Us</div>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <div class="passion click">Passion</div>
</a>

<div class="clickable7"></div>
```

Comment: what does your html look like

Comment: It's not a great idea to place functions in a for loop

Comment: What happens when you change `for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {` to `for (i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {`? It looks like you have 6 links, but you set your for-loop to terminate at 6 - an OOB error

Comment: Oh my... Drakes you are an absolute legend. All this time trying to figure out what's wrong with my code, i didn't think about making the length correct. Works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Paul, is there a better way to do this? I thought that repeating code was a big no no (obviously i'm just starting out my javascript adventures). I tried a for(let) and array.forEach but couldn't manage to get them working at all

Comment: why you just set a same class?

Comment: Was looking for a better way to do it, but each div is positioned absolutely with different positions, should be using id's rather then classes. Will get that changed up :)

Comment: you can `$('.about, .friends').hover(function () {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon inspection of the loop termination condition, I suggest changing

```
for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
```

because it looks like you have 6 links, but you set your for-loop to terminate at 6, so `titles[6]` will cause an OOB error which probably prevents the rest of your code from running.

---

It's also not advisable to put anonymous functions in a loop if you can help it.

I took the liberty of making another way to accomplish your task without using loops. Basically, you can put [data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) into the divs and use just one function to utilize the data and populate your hidden div. There are other ways, but this is just one humble solution.

Oh yes, you can use [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to prevent all the animation from chaining up between hovers.

```js
$('.click').hover(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  $('.clickable7')
    .text($this.data('text'))
    .css('padding-top', $this.data('padding'))
    .stop()
    .fadeIn(200);
}, function() {
  $('.clickable7')
    .stop()
    .fadeOut(200);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="positional">
  <a href="#about">
    <div class="about click" data-text="Find out about us" data-padding="37">About</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#friends">
    <div class="friends click" data-text="Meet our Friends" data-padding="57">Friends</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="purpose click" data-text="See our purpose" data-padding="97">Purpose</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="empowerment click" data-text="Be empowered!" data-padding="17">Empowerment</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#contact">
    <div class="contact click" data-text="Contact us" data-padding="69">Contact Us</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="passion click" data-text="Yay, passion!" data-padding="88">Passion</div>
  </a>
  <div class="clickable7"></div>
```

Comment: Should i be defining the function or is it just bad having a function inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop is terminated with a `;` which is a wrong syntax. As Drakes mentioned, defining anonymous functions inside a loop should be avoided as this usually creates closure issues. I have extracted the anonymous function like this:

```
(function($){
    var i,
        titles = [
        {
            name: ".about",
            text: "find out about us",
            padding: 137
        },
        {
            name: ".friends",
            text: "meet our friends",
            padding: 137
        }
    ];

    function bindHoverHandlers(index){
        var name = titles[index].name,
            text = titles[index].text,
            padding = titles[index].padding;

        $(name).hover(function () {
             $('.clickable7').text(text).css('padding-top', padding).fadeIn(200);
             $('.positional').css("background-image", "none");
         }, function () {
             $('.clickable7').fadeOut(200);
             $('.positional').css('background-image', 'url(assets/imgs/prototype6.png)');
         });
    }

    for (i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        bindHoverHandlers(i);
    }
}(window.jQuery));
```

Comment: Love it, wish i could submit multiple correct answers. Thanks for the alternative Rex, will keep this in mind if i decide it's easier to store my data in objects :)

Comment: Ah i did! But it says it wont be publicly displayed until i earn 15 rep. What a funny system! will try get some more rep so these things display :p